# I have a txt file which contains names, I want to extract first name and last name. I have created bash script but it's giving me an error

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Bash script to read out names from a text file. I have created below script and it's giving error

```
#!/bin/bash
file=testname.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
last=`awk -F ', ' '{ print $1 }'` $line
    echo $last
first='awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }'' $line
    echo $first
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, very good that you have shown your code which you tried keep it up.On SO we also encourage people to add their input and expected output too, could you please post input and expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You don't need to run awk on each line of a file, awk can parse the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the input data in the file is as follows

```
last_name, first_name
```

First field/column contains the last name and the second field/column is the first name. Using the shell.

```
while IFS=, read -r lastname firstname; do
   printf '%s %s\n' "$lastname" "$firstname" 
done < inputfile
```

Using awk

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s %s\n", $1, $NF}' inputfile
```